# How to add custom View Type in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I'm learning a lot about the Views in Drupal, but can't figure how to add new View types to the list (node, comment, user, etc).

The Query I'm trying to recreate in a View is something like "SELECT * from Quizz", which is a custom table, and I have already created a new content type named "Quizz" but I would like to be able to use it in the View module.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I have hopefully provided a helpful answer below, however it is worth noting that Views is not always the answer. Sometimes it is simpler to write the queries yourself. Views is only really needed if you need a lot of flexibility or integration with some views output modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [the data module](http://drupal.org/project/data), or the older [table wizard](http://drupal.org/project/tw) as a way to get views from generic tables. Both provide a UI. However I don't know how they will cope with complext relationships between tables.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use `hook_views_data`. Full documentation is in the help for the Views module, but [here's a bit of example code](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/function/hook_views_data/6).

Comment: So everytime I want to make a custom relationship on my View Type, I have to include the custom table in the hook_views_data as well? Right now my query has 4-5 relationship and the hook_views_data generated is like 1000 code lines! Not sure I understand correctly.